# Why doesn't my Spotify Play Queue & History sync across devices?

Tags: spotify

I have Spotify Premium. And this past weekend I played a bunch of music from my iPhone while I was out of town. Now I'm back, and I'm on my computer, and I can't figure out what it is that I played. My "History" under "Play Queue" only shows tracks that I've played on this device. And the mobile version of Spotify doesn't seem to feature "History."

How can I figure out what I played? Is there any way to sync "History" across devices so I know what I played from my account no matter where I played it?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you're looking for, but I would set up Spotify to scrobble to [last.fm](http://www.last.fm/) or [libre.fm](https://libre.fm/).  Last.fm support is built into Spotify on both the desktop and the [iPhone client](http://www.last.fm/group/Connect+Last.fm/forum/128131/_/2211205).  It has the additional benefit that you can set up other players to write what you're listening to to the same place.